# How do I important the environment that I already have to the .rmd file?

Tags: r

Let's say I'm trying to write a report using the PDF generated by `.rmd`. I have already written the code, and the output generated by the code is already stored in the R environment. How do I prevent the `.rmd` file from running the code again? It takes a lot of time to do so. I want the output that I already have to be directly imported to my `.rmd` output.

This should be a really simple task, so please bear with me.

Comment: It’s really not a simple task, and it’s fundamentally at odds with the design goals of R Markdown, since it makes the code from the document non-reproducible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oh I see... But is there a way to do it?

Comment: The `kniting` (report generation) is executed in separate session, therefore is not able to use the global environment data. There is a way to calculate it only once and store/reuse the results in/from cache (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html). It works for rmarkdown/bookdown/quarto.